# micropython qmi8658 exposing the AttitudeEngine quaternion

Tags: quaternions, micropython, imu, sensor-fusion, rp2040

I'm trying to expose the AttitudeEngine quaternion on the QMIi8658 mentioned in [the documentation](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/5/5f/QMI8658C.pdf). It's part of the [WaveShare RP2040-Touch-LCD-1.28](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/RP2040-Touch-LCD-1.28#Arduino_IDE_Series) module. Their original demo sketch exposes the accelerometer and Gyroscope sensors but the the internal fusion engine called AttitudeEngine that (if I understand the documentation properly) does all the fusion inside the QUM8658 IMU, thus leaving more room on the RP2040 for other calculations.

Here is my (failed) attempt at it: https://github.com/LazaroFilm/WaveShare-RP2040-Touch-LCD-1.28/blob/main/python/RP2040-LCD-1.28.py

I created a `Read_Raw_Quat()` function that is supposed to read the right register for the quaternion, but all I get are zeros...